# Remove items contained in an ArrayList from another ArrayList in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, arraylist, compare

I've got two ArrayLists `listA` and `listB`. `listB` is a subset of `listA`.
Now I want to remove all items contained in `listB` from `listA`.

Here is how my lists look like:

```
Name     ID    Domain
----     --    ------
item1    456   domain1
item2    716   domain2
item3    421   domain2
item4    796   domain1
```

```
Name     ID    Domain
----     --    ------
item2    716   domain2
item4    796   domain1
```

I've already tried using

```
$listA = $listA | Where-Object {$listB -notcontains $_}
```

but this did not work on my data.

Comment: did you try `compare-object`?

Comment: @4c74356b41 is right. If you had simple string values in either arraylists your example would work.

Comment: Your approach would only work if both lists contained the *same* object. It does not work if you have *different* objects with the same property values (identity vs. equality). Use `Compare-Object` as 4c74356b41 suggested.

Comment: Thanks this worked fine for me. I haven't thought about using `compare-object` in this contaxt.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `Compare-Object` cmdlet.
If your lists are like this:

```
$listA = @()
$listA += [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'item1' ; ID = '456'; Domain = 'domain1'}
$listA += [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'item2' ; ID = '716'; Domain = 'domain2'}
$listA += [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'item3' ; ID = '421'; Domain = 'domain2'}
$listA += [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'item4' ; ID = '796'; Domain = 'domain1'}

$listB = @()
$listB += [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'item2' ; ID = '716'; Domain = 'domain2'}
$listB += [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'item4' ; ID = '796'; Domain = 'domain1'}
```

then to remove all objects in `$listA` that are also in `$listB` taking all properties into account, do this:

```
$listA = $listA | Where-Object {(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $_ -DifferenceObject $listB -Property Name,ID,Domain).SideIndicator -eq '<=' }
```

After this, `$listA` will have only these two members left:

> ```
> Name  ID  Domain 
> ----  --  ------ 
> item1 456 domain1
> item3 421 domain2
> ```

**Edit**

Instead of actually naming the properties to compare like in the above, you can also collect them in a variable. For PS versions 3 and up you do this:

```
$props = $listA[0].psobject.properties.name
```

PowerShell versions below 3.0 use:

```
$props = $listA[0].psobject.properties | ForEach-Object { $_.name }
```

Then you can change the line to

```
$listA = $listA | Where-Object {(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $_ -DifferenceObject $listB -Property $props).SideIndicator -eq '<=' }
```

This of course only if both lists have the same property names to compare..

Answer (score 1):

Please note that variables $listA and $listB are arraylists.

This works only when working with arrays:

```
$listA = $listA | Where-Object {$listB -notcontains $_}
```

works only when working with arrays.

Therefore this should work with your data:

```
$arrayA = @()
$arrayA = $listA

$arrayB = @()
$arrayB = $listB

$arrayA = $arrayA | Where-Object {$arrayB -notcontains $_}
```

Given the fact that your code uses arraylists, don't forget to change the arrays back to arraylists like so:

```
$listA = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new($arrayA)
$listB = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new($arrayB)
```

If you ever feel confused what variable is what type, you can check its data type like this:

```
$listA.GetType()
```